# First load a page with ajax then with increasing intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I am currently using this code on one of my sites,
I want the test.php to load immediately, however it waits till after the interval.

Then if continues every minute untill the page closes. This can cause very large bandwith useage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("test.php", function (result) {
            $('#id').html(result);
        });
    }, 60000);
});
```

What I would like to achieve is.

Load the test.php on pageload.
Then load the page every 60 seconds
If the page has been open for 10 minutes double the intervals to 120sec.
20mins increase to 180 second intervals
30mins increase to 240 second intervals
And so on.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` to manage the increase in interval every 10 minutes, and use `setTimeout` to use that interval. To get the code executed immediately on page load, just rearrange the code a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 60000;

    setInterval(function () {
        interval += 60000;
    }, 600000); // every 10 minutes

    (function loop() {
        $.get("test.php", function (result) {
            $('#id').html(result);
        });
        setTimeout(loop, interval); // repeat after interval
    })(); // execute immediately
});
```

Comment: nice answer! :) nice thinking with the `interval` variable.

Comment: hey @trincot - very smart... like it

Answer (score 0):

## Generic Approach

*chainable factory function*

Create custom timer functions "on the fly".

```
var timer1 = timerFactory( fnCallback, iRepeats, iDelay, iSteps );
```

While runtime one can set all parameters.

```
timer1
    .setContext( { foo: true, bar: 'wow' } )
    .setCallback( function() { alert(this.bar) } )
    .setDelay( 10000 );
```

And destroy the timer when obsolete.

```
timer1.destroy()
```

```js
var timerFactory = function( _fnCallback, _iRepeat, _iDelay, _iSteps, _oContext ) {

    // sanitize arguments and set default values
    if ( typeof _fnCallback != 'function' ) {
        _fnCallback = function() {};
    }
    if ( typeof _iRepeat != 'number' || _iRepeat < 1 ) {
        _iRepeat = 10;
    }
    if ( typeof _iDelay != 'number' || _iDelay < 0 ) {
        _iDelay = 60000;
    }
    if ( typeof _iSteps != 'number' || _iSteps < 0 ) {
        _iSteps = _iDelay;
    }
    if ( typeof _oContext != 'object' ) {
        _oContext = this;
    }

    var i = _iRepeat,
        _getInterval = function() {
            if ( --i ) {
                return _iDelay;
            }
            i = _iRepeat;
            return _iDelay += _iSteps; 
        },
        _handle = function() {
            _fnCallback.call( _oContext );
            _setTimeout = setTimeout(_handle, _getInterval())
        };
        _handle();

    // public methods (chainable)
    this.destroy = function() {
        clearTimeout( _setTimeout );
        _fnCallback = _iRepeat = _iDelay = _iSteps =
        _oContext = i = _getInterval = _handle = undefined;
        return this;
    }
    this.setCallback = function( fnCallback ) {
        _fnCallback = fnCallback;
        return this;
    }
    this.setRepeats = function( iRepeat ) {
        _iRepeat = iRepeat;
        return this;
    }
    this.setDelay = function( iDelay ) {
        _iDelay = iDelay;
        return this;
    }
    this.setSteps = function( iSteps ) {
        _iSteps = iSteps;
        return this;
    }
    this.setContext = function( oContext ) {
        _oContext = oContext;
        return this;
    }

    // deploy public methods
    return this;

};


$(document).ready(function () {

/* actual question
timerFactory(
    function(){ $.get("test.php", function (result) { $('#id').html(result); }) }
)
*/

    // examples
    timerFactory( function() {$('#_0').append('ajax default: 10, 6000, 6000<br>')} );
    timerFactory( function() {$('#_1').append('1, 0, 250<br>')}, 1, 0, 250 );
    timerFactory( function() {$('#_2').append('3, 1500<br>')}, 3, 1500 );
    timerFactory( function() {$('#_3').append('1, 3000, ->destroy<br>')}, 1, 3000 ).destroy();

    // example with context and alternative syntax
    myClass = { // context example
        methFOO : function() {$('#_4').append('ALT meth1<br>')},
        methBAR : function() {$('#_4').append('ALT meth2<br>')}
    }
    timerFactory( myClass.methFOO, 1, 1, 1 )
        .setCallback( function() {this.methBAR()} )
        .setRepeats( 3 )
        .setDelay( 1000 )
        .setSteps( 500 )
        .setContext( myClass );

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="_0"></div>
<div id="_1"></div>
<div id="_2"></div>
<div id="_3"></div>
<div id="_4"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```